# unable to properly declare @media screen for mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I tried to declare an alternative formatting for mobile devices but the code after the opening bracket is not taken into account and I realised that the closing bracket isn't even taken into account (the color formatting is different). I declared @media screen and (max-width: 800px) and in the html code I have .

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  h2 {
      font-size: 24px;
     }
}
```

I am using coffeecup just to do a simple website and the code appears as such:
[Code in CoffeeCup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkU7k.png)

In the picture it shows that the closing bracket is not formatted properly.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks formatted properly in that screenshot.

Comment: The last closing bracket is not highlighted in blue like the others.

Comment: all right, i think it's bug your ide

Comment: but when I test it with my browser it still comes out wrong. The media attributes override the main ones.

Answer (score 0):

Your @media has no problems, it´s not highlighted because the last closing bracket is a second level bracket, it´s ok so. have you another @media in your code?

Comment: No that's the only one. I tried to even put it at the start of my code but I still get the same result.